# How to store new Facebook User IDs?

Tags: facebook

The user ids had been saved in our database when a customer had signed up through Facebook. Now if user tries to login through same Facebook account, the user id is not getting matched. The id sent by Facebook when the customer tried to login and the id saved in database is not getting matched. How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Facebook user ids are always to be treated as string values, not as numbers/integers. // Did you change app ids at some point? Since API v2.0, user ids are app-scoped, meaning every apps gets a different id for a specific user. If that’s the case: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Comment: Yes. Administrator account has been changed before few days.

Comment: It’s not about who’s admin of the app, but the app id itself (just to be clear.) If the app id has changed, then your only chance to map those users is what the document I linked to described.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks a lot. I checked, app id has been changed. I will try that out.